# missing ) after argument list -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, replace, syntax-error

Could someone explain me what I did wrong and why I have this `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`?

Here is the code:

```
function training(song){
  song.toString();
  var bla = new RegExp('BLA');
    alert(typeOf song);

  while (song = bla.test(song)) {
    song.replace(bla, ' ');
  }

  return song;
}
```

Also I have an error with .replace(). It says `song.replace() is not a function`.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, `toString` returns a string, it does not mutate the actual object in place.

Comment: It's [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) not `typeOf`

Comment: Why are you doing `while(song = bla.test(song))`?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

From the code I understand that you want to replace all,
Simply use `g` flag.

```
 function training(song){
    song = typeof song != typeof  'abc'?song.toString():void(0)
    var bla = new RegExp('BLA','g');
    alert(typeof song);  //you have a typo here
   song=song.replace(bla,' ');
    return song;
 }
```

Comment: Sagar V, it wasn't me. Thanks! I mixed up a little bit

Comment: Did the above solution helped you to reduce the code?

Comment: Why are you doing `song.toString()`? First of all it doesn't mutate the object in place, it *returns* the string. Also, if you call `replace` on it, it's already a string, no?

Comment: yes, it helped! I thought about indexOf when writing typeOf. And forgot about 'g'. So thank you one more time!

Comment: Show an example of argument you are passing? @ankaankina

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks I didn't noticed it beacuse i am in my mobile device. ankaankina, he is right I think you are already passing a string. toString() will not change the actual string, it returns a the string and we have to store it manually. **answer edited** you can remove the line or change with the line I added.